# How to change GPIO.BOARD TO GPIO.BCM for sensor SHT10

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, sensors, gpio

I want two scripts integrate in to one script.
Scripts for sensors SHT10 and MAX31855. Both make use of software SPI.
The SHT10 use GPIO.BOARD and the MAX31855 use GPIO.BCM.
The problem is that I get an error "ValueError: A different mode is already been set." I don't know how to resolve this because both sensors used different libraries. I think that the problem is in those libraries.
Is there an easy solution for this problem.
Running the scripts separately than there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) and then in the other program using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD).